# Some methods in my Ruby class appear to be private by default? Even though they are regular methods within the class

Tags: ruby, class, oop

```
class ProcessTrip < MetroCardClassMethods
attr_accessor :travel_history, :station, :destination 

def initialize  
   
end    
def update_balace_aumount(balance_details,trip_to,trip_complete)
      effective_tarif = trip_complete ? passenger_tarif_for(_passenger_type) / 2 : passenger_tarif_for(_passenger_type)
      trip_to['discount']= effective_tarif if trip_complete
      trip_to['discount']= 0 if !trip_complete
     if   balance_details["balance"].to_i < effective_tarif
      effective_trip_cost = effective_tarif  - balance_details["balance"].to_i
      trip_to["trip_cost"] +=  effective_trip_cost*0.02
      balance_details["balance"] = 0;
     else
      balance_details["balance"] =  balance_details["balance"].to_i - effective_tarif
     end      
    end 
end

def total_amount_collected ()
  @@vertex.each do |metro_id, travel_history| 
    result = find_amount_collected_for_metrocard(self.class.card_list[metro_id], travel_history)     
    result.each do |key,value| 
      self.class.collection[key]["cost"]+=value["trip_cost"];
      self.class.collection[key]["discount"]+=value["discount"];   
      self.class.collection[key]["passengers"]+=value["passenger"];     
    end
   
  end
  return @@collection
end

def find_amount_collected_for_metrocard(balance_details, trip_info)    
  trip_from={}
  trip_info.each do |station, destination| 
    @station = station             
    if _is_return_journey(trip_from)    
      process_trip_segment(trip_from,_destination,_station)   
      trip_from[_station]["trip_cost"] = passenger_tarif_for(_passenger_type) * 0.5    
      update_balace_aumount(balance_details, trip_from[_station], true); 
    
    else               
      process_trip_segment(trip_from,_station,_station)       
      trip_from[_station]["trip_cost"] = (trip_from[_station]["trip_cost"] || 0) + passenger_tarif_for(_passenger_type)          
      update_balace_aumount(balance_details, trip_from[_station], false);  

    end           
  end    

return  trip_from

end
```

I am trying to call   total_amount_collected from  an instance of Class ProcessTrip but I am getting an error saying it is a private method even though the method is a regular method and I have not put it under private keyword

```
trip.total_amount_collected
NoMethodError: private method `total_amount_collected' called for #<ProcessTrip:0x0000000110e33da0>
from (pry):3:in `get_total_collection'
```

I am calling the class from the following method

```
def get_total_collection
  trip =  ProcessTrip.new
  trip.total_amount_collected
  sort_passengers(total_collection); 
  print_summary(total_collection) if @print_summary
end
```

In addition I have superclass that is extended by ProcessTrip class

```
class MetroCardClassMethods
  @@card_list = []
  @@vertex = {};
  @@collection ={"CENTRAL"=>{"cost"=>0,"discount"=>0,"passengers"=>[]},"AIRPORT"=>{"cost"=>0,"discount"=>0,"passengers"=>[]}}
  @@station_from = {"CENTRAL"=>"AIRPORT","AIRPORT"=>"CENTRAL"}
  @@station = []

  def initialize(item)
    @travel_history =  {}  
    @metro_id = item["metro_id"] 
    @station = item["station"]
    @passenger_type = item["passenger_type"] 
    @destination = @@station_from[@station] 
  end

  class << self   
   
    def card_list=(card_list)
      @@card_list=card_list
    end 
    def card_list
      @@card_list
    end  
    def collection
      @@collection
    end  

    def station_from
      @@station_from
    end  
    def vertex
      @@vertex
    end  
  end  
 
end
```

can anyone explain why total_amount_collected is treated as private , whereas update_balace_aumount is treated a public method

Comment: Indent your code properly--you'll see the problem.

Comment: PSA: Empty argument lists can and should be omitted, as in `example()` becomes `example`. Avoid using `;` randomly, it is not necessary and just adds clutter. You are also leaning *way* too heavily on class variables which is a huge anti-pattern.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: @tadman I know class variables are used  rather heavily which is an antipattern,  however in my case the superclass holds the necessary class variables other classes might need, so other classes have to extend the superclass to gain access to all class variables. do you have any suggestion on managing class variables.

Comment: What you really need here is a whole other `class` to manage that, and then bridge that in via some class method. You're mixing up concerns here. Keep the "methods" class focused on one thing, and make a registry with normal instance variables somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `def`/`end` matching is off.  The last `end` before the `total_amount_collected` is closing the `ProcessTrip` class.  Then you're defining the `total_amount_collected` method outside of the class completely.  Here's a shorter example:

```rb
class MyClass
  def some_method
  end
end
def some_other_method
end
```

If you paste that into the IRB console and then call:

```rb
MyClass.new.some_other_method
```

You'll get a `private method` exception because `some_other_method` was defined as a new private method on the `Object` class not as a new public instance method on `MyClass`.

Comment: indeed , it was an indentation issue, the indention issue was in update_balace_aumount where an end statement after if else condition had closed the class function itself